# UITableView SelectedRow Heighlighting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

When user click the INR amount  Remaining Row will be disable
[image]

Again when user click the USD Amount Row remaing rows should be Disable.

i posted my trying code  please help me.

```
if([SelectedIndexPath containsIndex:indexPath.row])
{
    NSString *StrCurrency=[CurrencyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",StrCurrency);

    if ([StrCurrency isEqualToString:@"USD"]) {
        cell.HideView.hidden=NO;
    }
    else{
        cell.HideView.hidden=YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"selected");

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Unselected");
    cell.HideView.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: do the same calcultion in `cellforrowatindexpath` also

Comment: i posted code is not working.

Comment: i understood the logic thanks Anbu.Kathik.

Comment: good my bro....

Comment: i have one more problem bro when i selected row showing hilate but remaining row not disable i posted my updated CellForRowAtindexPath code please check my updated code

Comment: in here what is the use of this `if([SelectedIndexPath containsIndex:indexPath.row])`

Comment: if([SelectedIndexPath containsIndex:indexPath.row]) this is use for user Which row is select for checking.